Resources for equity risk management industry best practices
Has anyone got any papers that can help me lower volatility of a market neutral equity portfolio?
I have a basic covariance variance matrix which is used to optimize the portfolio but I am wondering if there any other concepts / ideas / methods to further reduce volatility.
